# Android Scrollview doesn't scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I am trying to make an whole view of a scrollView but the scrollView doesn't scroll.

Please help me:)

Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
   >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    >

 ////some content here

 </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: what content inside your linearlayout? is there recyclerview inside it?

Comment: its : android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Comment: scrollview will affect if the views inside linearlayout exceeding the device view.. try to put more views inside it..

Comment: not 1 but some TextInputLayout inside scrolview

Comment: add `android:fillViewport="true"` in scrollview section.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ScrollView `android:layout_height` to match parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your scroll view to `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` and set the `height` attribute to `match_parent`

Comment: it doesn't scroll at all